# PHPExcel: how to get hidden cell values / Scientific Number in Number?

Tags: phpexcel, phpexcelreader

In PHPExcel is there any format available to get proper reading of the order item value as shown in picture.

[image: Excel Sheet Snapshot]

I read whole the document but not find any solution for this problem.

For the date filled also if the data is shown ###### like way then how to get that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Excel, numbers that are larger than a certain size will be shown in scientific format (e.g. `1.40E+15`) unless you set a format mask for that cell which says otherwise. The solution is to set an appropriate format mask, or to set the value as a string value.

In MS Excel, if a string value is wider than the column size, then it will be shown as `######`. The solution is to increase the column size.

**EDIT**

I can't tell you what the best column size is? That all depends on your data.... but you can either set columns to a fixed size using:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getColumnDimension('D')
    ->setWidth(32);
```

or set a column to autocalculate the width

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getColumnDimension('D')
    ->setAutoSize(true);
```

Exactly as described in the [PHPExcel docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-a-columns-width)

Note that we do spend time and effort writing this documentation to try and answer your questions: it is worth reading.